# Math specification with a Regression with SARIMA errors

Tags: r, regression, time-series, arima

Good day everyone, I have one question so I'm asking for your help.

I'm working on a model with a Regression with SARIMA errors, I already have the model and the forecast, but I need the mathematically specification for the model, the order is (1,1,0) (1,0,0,12), and here we have the coefficients, so how can I build the model if the algebraic example is this one? Because I can’t understand how to specify the model for this case with a regression

Regression with ARIMA(1,1,0)(1,0,0)[12] errors

Coefficients:
ar1   0.3972
sar1  -0.4102
xreg  0.0380

s.e.

ar1   0.1108

sar1  0.1216

xreg  0.0113

I really appreciate your help.

[image: Regression with ARIMA error example]

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=SARIMA+formula